# Array Out of Bounce Exception for Jar, but not Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When I convert my `Java` project into a Jar file, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception  of -2 occurs in line 3 of this section of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < copy.get(copy.size() - 2).size(); i++) {
    if (!copy.get(copy.size() - 2).get(i).toString().equals(" ")) {
        startLocations[index] = Integer.parseInt(copy.get(copy.size() - 2).get(i).toString());
        index++;
    }
}
```

I find this very strange because the program runs perfectly fine in Eclipse, and the size of `copy`, a `2D ArrayList` tempoarily holding the grid of a maze is 9. The code fails when I convert it to a Jar and I run it from cmd. Here is the full relevant code below. All the files are in their correct locations.

```
String fileName = "maze.txt";
String line = null;
ArrayList < ArrayList < Square >> grid = new ArrayList < ArrayList < Square >> ();

try {
    // Setup FileReader, BufferedReader, and LineReader
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    int row = 0;

    // Get all the lines inside the maze file
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        ArrayList < Square > lineList = new ArrayList < Square > ();

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            String letter = Character.toString(line.charAt(i));

            if (letter.equals("L")) {
                lineList.add(new LockedSquare(row, i, letter));
            } else {
                lineList.add(new Square(row, i, letter));
            }

            row++;
        }

        grid.add(lineList);
    }

    // Cut down grid to only the maze

    ArrayList < ArrayList < Square >> copy = grid;

    int length = grid.size();

    grid = new ArrayList < ArrayList < Square >> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; i++) {
        grid.add(copy.get(i));
    }

    // Start position

    int[] startLocations = new int[2];

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < copy.get(copy.size() - 2).size(); i++) {
        if (!copy.get(copy.size() - 2).get(i).toString().equals(" ")) {
            startLocations[index] = Integer.parseInt(copy.get(copy.size() - 2).get(i).toString());
            index++;
        }
    }

    int playerX = startLocations[0];
    int playerY = startLocations[1];
}
// Exceptions
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: maze.txt not found");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error reading maze.txt");
}
```

Comment: @markspace What do you mean by Tigger needs a new spring?

Comment: You can try to print the arrays `grid` and `copy` just before the `//start position` and see what's inside them.  or add a break point and debug.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan The grids in Eclipse work fine, but on the jar file, they are blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your jar file is unable to find `maze.txt` .

change `String fileName = "maze.txt";` 
to 
`String fileName = <absolute-path-for-maze.txt> ;` and it should be through in jar

Comment: Just for clarification, by absolute path do you mean the exact path for my file? Like this: C:\Users\henrydavidzhu\Desktop\Lacid

Comment: @Satya This works right after I inputted the actual maze. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Woops. I was so stupid. My maze.txt file in the same folder as my JAR has no content in it.